# Where can I set the ES6 option for jshint?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jshint

I tried:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
```

but got an error when running grunt:

[image]

This is supposed to be the preferred method as `esnext` is being deprecated.  See here - http://jshint.com/docs/options/#esnext

Comment: does `esnext` still work for you?

Comment: How do I put it in : `esnext: true` or just `esnext`?

Comment: How do I check the version ?  It was installed automatically by npm.

Comment: `esnext: true` works ... npm is supposed to install the newest version.  Strange ... someone is lying, either npm or jshint.

Comment: Jshint --version perhaps ?

Comment: it's a plugin so there is no jslint from the command line.

Comment: @cadegalt problem solved or do you need more help?

Comment: @Code - why is your name CodeiSir?

Answer (score 8):

You can set the 'esversion' option in your gruntfile.js, like so:

```
jshint: {
    files: ['dist/*.js'],
    options: {
        'esversion': 6,
    }
},
```